# ScrollIntoView with animation

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a groupped gridview and i need to scroll on group with animation. Now i use method `GridView.ScrollIntoView(object item)` which works good, but i need to add some animation.

Plan: 
I want extract ScrollViewer from gridview using extension method `GetFirstDescendantOfType<T>` from WinRTXamlToolkit and then use method of ScrollViewer `ChangeView(..)`. I can get position of Container from gridview `ContainerFromIndex(int)` or `ContainerFromItem(object)` but the container is not rendered and methods returns null, because gridview panel is virtualized.

How can i do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an animated scroll - you can use WinRT XAML Toolkit's ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation() extension or if you are targeting Windows 8.1 - you can use the new ScrollViewer.ChangeView() method that supports animated scroll.